# Item in loop is undefined

Tags: html, mongodb, meteor, ionic2

I have an issue that I don't understand, and if anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

I am using Ionic2 with Meteor/MongoDb.

I have a cursor:

```
private messages: Mongo.Cursor<Message>;
```

On the server I do an insert:

```
Messages.insert({
  chatId: chatId,
  senderId: senderId,
  content: content,
  readByReceiver: false,
  createdAt: new Date()
});
```

It triggers an observable as expected:

```
    this.messages.observe({
      added: (message) => this.addMessageToLocal(message)
    });

  private addMessageToLocal(newMessage: Message): void {
     // here I print the message, and it is as expected
  }
```

Also, I do a `forEach` through the `messages`, and they are all populated as expected.

**Issue**

My problem is in the `html`. I loop trough the `messages` cursor. It displays each item as expected. Until I add a `message` (as above). Then the new `message` from the `html` is `undefined`.

```
<template ngFor let-message [ngForOf]="messages">
        <div *ngIf="!exists(message)" class="message-wrapper">
            <div *ngIf="message.changeDate">
                <center><span class="message-datetime">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY'}}</span></center>
            </div>
            <div [class]="'message message-' + message.ownership">
                <div class="message-content">server:{{message.content}}</div>
                <span class="time-tick">
<span *ngIf="message" class="message-timestamp">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
                <div *ngIf="message && message.readByReceiver && senderId == message.senderId">
                    <span class="checkmark">
        <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
        <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
    </span>
                </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
```

The final `message` item in the loop (the new one added), is `undefined`. i.e. In the `*ngIf="!exists(message)"` function called from the `html`, I print the `message`, and its's `undefined`.

So in the `html` I loop over the `messages` Cursor, and the new one is `undefined`.  However, if even in the same function (`exists()`), I loop over the `messages` Cursor again, just to test it, none of the items are `undefined`.

**Question**

Please can anyone suggest what I can do to **not** have the last `item` in the `Cursor` as `undefined`?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I am getting something I don't understand.

When I call a function from the `html` as follows, `message` is not `undefined`:

`{{ formatMessage(message) }}`

But if I call a function as follows, it is `undefined`:

`*ngIf="!exists(message)"`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using:

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

But I still think there may be a bug in Angular